# error in your SQL syntax near

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, servlet-3.0

I need help. I'm developing app for uploading text files. For this moment I encountered error which I cannot clearly understand. Here is my code:

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Servlet based API for querying text file</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Please choose file</h3>
    <div class="container">
    <form action="TextProccessing" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="browseTxt">Upload file:</label> 
            <input type="file" name="browseTxt" id="browseTxt" value="select text file">
            <p class="help-block">
                <b>Note:</b> Please choose .txt file only
            </p>
        </div>

        <BUTTON class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Upload</BUTTON>

    </form>
    </div>

    <h2>Place for text</h2>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**TextProccessing**

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
public class TextProccessing extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static String RESULT_PAGE = "/result.jsp";
    private final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/textfilesdb";
    private final String dbUser = "root";
    private final String dbPassword = "root";
    // for this moment
    private String ﬁle_Name_test = "ﬁle_Name_test";
    private String file_size_test = "file_size_test";
    private String ﬁleCreationDate_test = "ﬁleCreationDate_test";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        Part filePart = request.getPart("browseTxt");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null; // message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO files(ﬁle_Name, file_size, ﬁleCreationDate, text_file) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, ﬁle_Name_test);
            statement.setString(2, file_size_test);
            statement.setString(3, ﬁleCreationDate_test);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(4, inputStream);
            }

            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(RESULT_PAGE).forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

it seems ok but I have such error stacktrace

> browseTxt 1189 text/plain
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?le_Name,
>   file_size, ?leCreationDate, text_file) values ('?le_Name_test',
>   'file_' at line 1     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
>     at com.controller.TextProccessing.doPost(TextProccessing.java:68)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

And my DB structure

create database TextFilesDB;

use TextFilesDB;

> CREATE TABLE `files` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `ﬁle_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,   `file_size` varchar(45) DEFAULT
>   NULL,   `ﬁleCreationDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `text_file`
>   mediumblob,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16

Comment: There's something odd about `ﬁle_Name`; the `fi` are a single (UTF-8?) character, not 2 ascii characters `f` and `i`; the mysql error shows `?` there.

Comment: Yes, I didn't noticed this place. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have some format problem with the columns names. Can you try to replace

```
INSERT INTO files(ﬁle_Name, file_size, ﬁleCreationDate, text_file) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

by

```
INSERT INTO files(file_Name, file_size, fileCreationDate, text_file) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem.

Comment: Notice that the "fi" syllables in the "file_Name" and "fileCreationDate" are NOT the character "f" plus the character "i". The they are the U+FB01 unicode character: "ﬁ" - you can test it by selecting the syllable on your code above. You'll see that the "ﬁ" isn't composed by two characters, but by only one. Sometimes it happens when you copy and paste a code directly from the internet into your text editor. It's especially problematic with quotes. They usually are replaced by its extended Unicode character and your program doesn't compile.